# Multiple scope binding in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have two scope variables in my controller.

```
$scope.list = {title: 'Lorem Ipsum'}

$scope.data = {'Lorem Ipsum' : {'keys': 'values'}}
```

In my view I want to access :

```
<div>{{data['list.title'].keys}}</div>
```

This is kind of requirement, I dont want `{{data['Lorem Ipsum']}}` which actually works but there are some dynamic binding that i need to do. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the single quotes from your array index:

```
<div>{{data[list.title].keys}}</div>
```

Comment: Getting empty object like {{}}

Comment: I've just tested this with your example data, and the text "values" shows up in the div for me as expected... Is what you've provided, exactly the same data you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Do just:

```
<div>{{data[list.title].keys}}</div>
```

Comment: Getting empty object like {{}}

Comment: I know what exactly it is, Thanks buddy